# Insert image in my own collection using Meteor CollectionFS:filesystem

Tags: image, meteor, collectionfs

I am using Meteor CollectionFS Package(cfs:filesystem) to upload image.

I have used this syntax:

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [imageStore]
});
```

but it stores image in new collection that is `'cfs.images.filerecord'` instead of this collection I want to store in my own collection.

how it is possible?